# LEGO RCX hardware schematic

Tags: rcx

Where can I find the hardware schematic for the LEGO RCX brick?
I spend a lot of time but unfortunately didn't find any useful information.

Answer (score 3):

There are partial reverse engineered schematics done by Mark Bellis [here](http://www.brickshelf.com/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi?f=109570)